# Contenteditable - Clone text from span to span on type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a Contenteditable span tag and want it to auto copy what I type to other span tags.

I.e

Cost        - 0.00 - This Is the editable span tag. 
Sub Total - 0.00 
Total         - 0.00

Cost        - 1.00 When changed the other values are also changed straight away.
Sub Total - 1.00 
Total         - 1.00

The html im using:

```
<td><span data-prefix>£</span><span contenteditable>0.00</span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were after? Using jQuery:

```
<span class="result" data-prefix></span>
<span class="edit" contenteditable>0.00</span>

$(".edit").on("keyup", function() {
    $(".result").empty().text( "£" + $.trim($(this).text()) );
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gs6hfunt/)